# How to get resource URL from AWS S3 in a golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to get public permanent (not signed) URL of a resource using golang and [official aws go sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go). In Java AWS S3 SDK there's a method called [`getResourceUrl()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getResourceUrl-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) what's the equivalent in go?

Comment: my google foo says  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html

Comment: I expanded my answer with how to get get non pre signed urls.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how you get presigned URLs using the go sdk:

```
func GetFileLink(key string) (string, error) {
    svc := s3.New(some params)

    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(a bucket name),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }

    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(params)

    url, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute) // Set link expiration time
    if err != nil {
        global.Log("[AWS GET LINK]:", params, err)
    }

    return url, err
}
```

If what you want is just the URL of a public access object you can build the URL yourself:

```
https://<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<key>
```

Where `<region>` is something like `us-east-2`. So using go it will be something like:

```
url := "https://%s.amazonaws.com/%s/%s"
url = fmt.Sprintf(url, "us-east-2", "my-bucket-name", "some-file.txt")
```

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) is a list of all the available regions for S3.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with this:
`fmt.Sprintf("https://s3-%s.amazonaws.com/%s/%s", region, bucket, key)`. Also there's a problem with the key (url path) as it can contain unescaped characters like semicolons, etc... That's why there's a separate method in Java SDK...

Answer (score 0):

Updated version for sdk-go-v2 how to get presigned URLs

```
package aws

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

// GetFileLink returns a presigned URL for a file in AWS S3.
// This function utilizes the aws-go-v2 SDK.
func GetFileLink(cfg aws.Config, key string) (string, error) {
    // Get the bucket name from the environment variable.
    bucketName := os.Getenv("BUCKET_NAME")

    // Create a new S3 client from the configuration.
    s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    presignClient := s3.NewPresignClient(s3Client)

    // Get the presigned URL for the file.
    presignUrl, err := presignClient.PresignGetObject(context.Background(),
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
            Key:    aws.String(key)},

    s3.WithPresignExpires(time.Minute*15))
    if err != nil {
        // If there's an error getting the presigned URL, return the error.
        return "", err
    }

        return presignUrl.URL, nil
}
```

Example for using:

main.go

```
func main() {
    // Load the AWS SDK configuration.
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to load AWS SDK config, %v", err)
    }

    // Set the file key.
    fileKey := "path/to_your/file.txt"

    // Get the presigned URL for the file.
    url, err := adminpanel.GetFileLink(cfg, fileKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to get file link, %v", err)
    }

    // Print the file URL.
    fmt.Println("File URL:", url)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks almost clean:

```
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/private/protocol/rest"

...

params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(a bucket name),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
}
req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(params)
rest.Build(req) // aws method to build URL in request object
url = req.HTTPRequest.URL.String() // complete URL to resource
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.