# Simple Example of how to get the un-presigned s3 object url using the golang aws sdk v2

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I see lots of example on google/stackoverflow using s3client.GetRequestObject which is now removed from v2 of the sdk

```
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }
    req, _ := client.GetRequestObject(params)
```

[How to get resource URL from AWS S3 in a golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575011/how-to-get-resource-url-from-aws-s3-in-a-golang)

I looked through the sdk v2 examples:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/gov2/s3/

And nothing stands out to me as an example of how to do this.

I don't want to download, just provide a link to download

Comment: The S3 URL is just `"s3://bucket/key`" You can use basic string concatenation to get that URL from the values you currently have (unless I'm missing some aspect of your question)

Comment: thanks but I want the https url not the s3 url. Something like 
```
https://bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/key
```
I'm not sure I can always assume the rest of the domain is just "." + region + ".amazonaws.com"; can I ?
.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of getting presigned URL for an object with an expiration time:

```
s3client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
presignClient := s3.NewPresignClient(s3client)
presignedUrl, err := presignClient.PresignGetObject(context.Background(),
    &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("bucket-name"),
        Key:    aws.String("key-name"),
    },
    s3.WithPresignExpires(time.Minute*15))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(presignedUrl.URL)
```

See my article about S3 presigned URLs in this link https://ronen-niv.medium.com/aws-s3-handling-presigned-urls-2718ab247d57